# Beginner question: create an object - error of Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#

Please bear with me, I'm only a few hours in to learning c#.

I am trying to create an object of type 'Hotel' that includes the following values:

- Name
- Number of Rooms

And then prints the name of the hotel to the screen.

I am receiving an error in Program.cs of
`"Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration [FirstApp]`
.... and I don't understand why.

I have 2 classes - Program.cs and Hotel.cs.

Program.cs has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FirstApp
{    
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
          var hotel = new Hotel("Paradise Beach", 200);
          Console.WriteLine($"The name of the hotel is {hotel.name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Hotel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FirstApp
{   
    public class Hotel
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}                          
        public int Rooms {get; set;}                            

    public Hotel(string name, int rooms)   
        {                           
            this.Name = name;
            this.Rooms = rooms;
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help, Ive spent nearly 35 hours between pluralsight and this app and I'm really disheartened I'm not even able to print to screen properly.

Comment: Which line is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: Line 12 on program.cs, so the line below Console.Writeline

Comment: `{hotel.name}` should be `{hotel.Name}`

Comment: There isn't a `(` on line 12 of what you've shown us... the code you've provided compiles fine for me once you've changed `hotel.name` to `hotel.Name` in the `Console.WriteLine` call.

Comment: It would be useful to know what toolset you're using - is this in Visual Studio, VS Code, something else? Also, the version you're using of that toolset...

Comment: @JonSkeet - thank you! I'd like to explain why I think it worked so that I truly understand why it did, make sure my grasp of the fundamentals is accurate....!
When creating an object of the Hotel class, its constructor requires two parameters - string name, int rooms (lower case n / r respectively). name is what is used to pass the argument to, and in turn then stored in the field Name.

In essence, I was trying to call the parameter, rather than the field that stored the state!

Can't believe the real Jon Skeet answered my question. I've been watching your YT videos on design patterns!

Comment: @JonSkeet - hit the character limit for my response, just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @Zer0 - thank you for taking the time to respond, really appreciate it. I beleive I understand why the correction worked (explanation in comments above), I'll revisit Scott Allens C# fundamentals regarding fields. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's worth differentiating between *properties* and *fields*, but other than that, yes, that's why it was wrong... but it still doesn't explain why you got that error. I'd expect to see a very different error message from the one you've reported.